# Get list of Account object using lightning ui* adaptor along with all record in list view without using apex class

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, lwc-wire-getlistui

I am trying to display Account list view just like we see in Salesforce standard list view
so I am trying to use lightning ui* adaptor
I have used this module - lightning/uiListsApi and adaptor config is - getListInfoByName
Please check my code

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getListInfoByName } from 'lightning/uiListsApi';
import ACCOUNT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Account';

export default class GetListAPI extends LightningElement {
  listViewData;
  @wire(getListInfoByName, { objectApiName: ACCOUNT_OBJECT.objectApiName, listViewApiName: 'AllAccounts' })
    listViewWire({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            console.log('data inside list view',data);
            this.listViewData = data.displayColumns;
            this.error = undefined;
        } else if (error) {
            this.data = undefined;
            console.log('data inside list view',error);
            console.error(error);
        }
    }
}

<template>
    <lightning-card title="wireListInfoByName">
      <template lwc:if={listViewData}>
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
          <template for:each={listViewData} for:item="col">
            <p key={col.fieldApiName}>{col.fieldApiName} : {col.label}</p>
          </template>
        </div>
      </template>
    </lightning-card>
  </template>
```

Here I can see only list view field name
but I want to see all records in a lightning datatable

I know this is not the correct way , as it only display fields/column name
I need to display Account list view complete with all account records in the form of list

Please suggest me what I should do

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try fetching the Account data through an Apex Controller like this:

```
public with sharing class AccountController {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Account> getAccounts() {
        return [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account LIMIT 200];
    }
}
```

then your js would like something like this:

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import getAccounts from '@salesforce/apex/AccountController.getAccounts';
import { getListInfoByName } from 'lightning/uiListsApi';
import ACCOUNT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Account';

export default class GetListAPI extends LightningElement {
    listViewData;
    accountData;
    columns = [ 
        { label: 'Account Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text' }
    ];

    @wire(getListInfoByName, { objectApiName: ACCOUNT_OBJECT.objectApiName, listViewApiName: 'AllAccounts' })
    listViewWire({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            console.log('data inside list view',data);
            this.listViewData = data.displayColumns;
            this.error = undefined;
        } else if (error) {
            this.data = undefined;
            console.log('data inside list view',error);
            console.error(error);
        }
    }

    @wire(getAccounts)
    accountDataWire({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            console.log('Account data', data);
            this.accountData = data;
            this.error = undefined;
        } else if (error) {
            this.accountData = undefined;
            console.error(error);
        }
    }
}
```

html:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="wireListInfoByName">
        <template if:true={listViewData}>
            <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
                <template for:each={listViewData} for:item="col">
                    <p key={col.fieldApiName}>{col.fieldApiName} : {col.label}</p>
                </template>
            </div>
        </template>
        <template if:true={accountData}>
            <lightning-datatable
                key-field="Id"
                data={accountData}
                columns={columns}
                hide-checkbox-column="true">
            </lightning-datatable>
        </template>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Comment: thank you for reply, but I dont want to use Apex class, is there any way to use lightning *ui adaptor only to show list view of Object